# Webpage performance IE only JS/CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, performance

When we keep JS and CSS files for IE only with  tags, do other browsers read it. I understand they ignore it but do they download all the files and then ignore it or vice versa. My reason for asking is page performance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Do you mean conditional comments? Can you show some code?

Comment: Yes, I meant conditional comments. I didn't know the word for it. My question has been answered. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The files are ignored by other browsers.

Note how

```
<!--[if IE]>
    You are using IE (IE5+ and above).
<![endif]-->
```

starts and ends within `<!-- normal html comments -->`. They are treated special by IE, but other browsers just see a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment), then only IE can parse these so only IE will even comprehend that there is a resource to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions surround the IE specific resources, they shouldn't be requested. You can use a tool such as Fiddler or HttpFox (for Firefox) to confirm.

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful. I used 'Net' tab in Firebub to see exactly what loads when a page is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Other browsers just see the comment markers and skip over them. IE is the only browser to which they have any special meaning.